# "Recommended Viewing" before watching Doctor Who: "Day of the Doctor"?

Tags: doctor-who, suggested-order

My fiancee would like to watch "Day of the Doctor" in theatres.

Unfortunately, we have only watched up to season 5 (the one ending in "The Big Bang"), so I fear that by jumping straight to "Day of the Doctor" I might be missing important or interesting backstory.  I'm afraid we probably do not have time to watch all of season 6 and 7 before it will no longer be in theaters.

In order of most important to least important, what videos would you suggest we should watch before watching the "Day of the Doctor"?  Possible candidates:

- Specific episodes of Season 6
- Specific episodes of Season 7
- The Last Day
- The Night of the Doctor
- The 1996 TV film "Doctor Who"

We'll probably figure out how much time we have, and watch that list of videos (in airing order, of course).

Comment: It seems to me that the special was designed to be "understandable" to newcomers - that is, it is not quite dependent of the rest of the series, so that it fares better in theatres. There are several references, but none are essential for getting the plot. If you've seen up to Big Bang, you should be fine (Clara isn't key in this special). I suppose that, at most, it wouldn't be bad to watch the prequels (like Night of the Doctor) - they won't spoil seasons 6 or 7 to you anyway. Have fun!

Comment: It helps if you're familiar with the concept of "xxth anniversary specials" that usually feature multiple incarnations of the Doctor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None are essential. Night of the Doctor is worth watching before. Peter Davison's 5 Doctors' reboot is a hilarious complement, watchable before or after. Mark Gatiss' An adventure in time and space is a good introduction to the classic series.